# Detect if button in specific window is visible

Tags: monitoring

I'd like to know if there is any way to detect visibility of some control in some application. I need to periodically monitor if there is specific application opened and visible on screen and if specific label/panel/button in that application is shown on screen.

I know about tools like `xwininfo` and `xdootool`, but these are all about windows, not content (controls in those windows).

I needed similar thing in Windows world, many years ago and there was a relatively simple way on how to iterate controls in application. Αlso it's easy in the HTML world. So I'm wondering, why can't I find any info about this for the Linux desktop world?

It is possible?
Is this task related to desktop environment, toolkit, X system or something like that?

Comment: Any "smart" solution would be toolkit dependent. But more low level, you can monitor content changes to any X11 window with the "Damage" extension, extract the pixel data with `XGetImage()` and search through it ;-) I don't know of anything readily made doing that -- but there could be a nice utility: select some area from the screen (eg. a button or icon), and then be notified when it disappears or appears again ;-)

Comment: You can use the accessibility tools for your toolkit to get the information on windows, elements, current status ...